# Добавление shared google spread sheet в google drive

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Не получается добавить гугл таблицу в гугл драйв по ссылке. Я так понимаю, то ли ссылка старая, то ли таблица старая, из-за этого ссылка работает не так, как надо. Вот например ссылки, которые заканчиваются на /edit нормально добавляются и отображаются в google drive, в отличие от ссылок, которые заканчиваются на /pubhtml, которые не сохраняются в google drive и постоянно приходится искать ссылку для того, чтобы открыть таблицу. Выглядят страницы, кстати, тоже по-разному. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Формат ссылки уже обсуждался - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740118/has-the-google-sheets-published-url-suddenly-changed-to-a-different-format . Что касается добавления в драйв, то добавлять-то следует **саму таблицу**, а не результат её web публикации (фактически - web-интерфейс).

Answer (score 0):

Данный вопрос касается двух аспектов знания о Таблицах Google.

Во-первых, вопрос публикации Таблиц, который рассматривается в справке [Как опубликовать документ, таблицу, презентацию или форму Google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?hl=ru). Необходимо разделить для себя понятия, что "Гугл Таблица" - это приложение или сервис; "ссылки оканчиваются на" - это адреса; "Google Drive" - сервис или приложение. При перемешивании всего этого в тарабарщину смысла не получится.

Ссылки вида `/pubhtml` ведут на общедоступные страницы, которые генерируются сервисом Таблиц Google (внизу в футере об этом написано как "Published by Google Sheets") для отображения информации, которая содержится в определенном диапазоне определенной Таблицы Google. Эти ссылки не имеют отбратной связи (вы не можете по ним найти Таблицу-источник) и представляют из себя самостоятельные страницы. **Коротко**, эти ссылки нельзя "добавить в/на" Диск Google.

Во-вторых, вопрос добавления в/на Диск рассматривается в справке [Как найти доступные вам файлы и папки](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375057?hl=ru). См. раздел "Как добавить файлы в раздел 'Мой диск'".

Необходимо понять, что любые файлы (например, Таблицы, ссылки на которые оканчиваются на `/edit`), доступные вашему пользователю, могут быть видны в приложении Диска, кроме публичных/общедоступных файлов, которые необходимо добавлять самостоятельно. **Коротко**, эти ссылки уже доступны или можно "добавить в/на" Диск Google.

К сожалению, понять, что такое "shared google spread sheet в google drive" невозможно, но оно и не надо.